# Find number of times we have a character in a row in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on elasticsearch and facing an issue that how many time a word comes in a row at the time search records.

Like I have following rows:

```
{
 { "user":"Aniket", "postDate":"2016-04-26","body":"Search as we discuss yesterday one time word", "title":"One time word"}
    }, 
{
 "user": "aniket", "postDate": "2016-04-26", "body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word word word" , "title": "Four times word"}
    }, 
{"user": "aniket", "postDate": "2016-04-26", "body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word word" , "title": "Three times word"}
    }, 
{"user": "aniket", 
    "postDate": "2016-04-26", 
    "body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word" ,
    "title": "Two times word"
}
```

I have above four rows under user aniket and we have "word" in each row but sometimes it goes two,three,four or one time.
I need the result like if I search for "word" and we found word four times in the result than it will come at the top like:
1. word word word word
2. word word word
3. word word
4. word
I tried with score too but score is not going to provide me any information related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need script sorting. Something like this:

```
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "termInfo=_index['body'][term].tf();return termInfo;",
      "params": {
        "term": "word"
      },
      "lang": "groovy",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
```

And enable Groovy scripting in `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true
```

And, also, you need to use a proper analyzer. For you case, for example, using the `standard` analyzer (the default one) you won't get a split at `easy.word`. For that sorting to work, you'd need an analyzer that will split at `.` for example.

Comment: Tried to get the result using following command :curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search' -d '{"fields": ["id", "body", "title", "user", "postDate"],"query":{"term":{"user":"aniket"}},"sort": {"_script": {"type": "number","script": {"inline": "termInfo=_index['body'][term].tf();return termInfo;","params": {"term": "word"}},"order": "desc"}}}' but did not get the respone

Comment: Hm, can you provide the mapping of your `post` type, please?

Comment: I am new in elasticsearch so there is no mapping, I just add the records using cmd and wish search.

Comment: Ok then. Get the result of `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_mapping"`

Comment: Here is the mapping {
  "blog" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "post" : {
        "properties" : {
          "body" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "postDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "user" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: getting error Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }]

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: cygnet@CIPL-6PC205:~/Homestead$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Hyperstorm",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.3.9",
    "build_hash" : "0915c7306e6264ba21a6cb7609b93545ccc32ef1",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-02-19T12:34:48Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.9"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110514/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: Updated my answer to fit with ES 1.3.9.

Comment: Impossbile. I've tested it with ES 1.3.7.

Comment: And now I tested with ES 1.3.9. And there is no error.

Comment: I added it in etc/elasticsearch/elasticesearch.yml in ubuntu 14.04 (script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true) and tried  now get this error  [nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }] ----- Do I need to restart elastic search or what?

Comment: Yes, after any changes in the config file, ES needs to be restarted.

Comment: Stop and start elastic search now get ["failures" : [ {
      "index" : "multisearch",
      "shard" : 0,
      "status" : 500,
      "reason" : "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[multisearch][0]: query[filtered(body:word)->cache(_type:blogpost)],from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:\"_script\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.DoubleScriptDataComparator$InnerSource@7bde289a>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: body for class: Script5]]; "
    }]

Comment: I thought your index is called `blog` not `multisearch`. I don't know what you are doing and testing there but is very confusing.

Comment: No both are the same, I created one instance for my testing and one for you. But I got the same error in both cases.

Comment: You can say for this query (curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "body": "word"
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
 "type": "number",
 "script": "termInfo=_index['body'][term].tf();return termInfo;",
 "params": {
     "term": "word"
 },
 "lang": "groovy",
 "order": "desc"
 }
    }
}') I got this error ("index" : "blog",
      "shard" : 2,
      "status" : 500,nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: body for class: Script5]])

Comment: Ok. For this query remove the entire `sort` part and run it again. Does it work?

Comment: Yes its give me the result even if I use simple sort then body and order by asc than also it works properly but not is our word count case

Comment: Are you looking for the solution, I am left with this last thing. Waiting?

Comment: I don't understand where that exception is coming from. I used your mapping, that exact query and ES 1.3.9 and I don't get that exception.

Comment: Are using it in PHP or java? because here I have ubuntu 14.04 with homestead and running on that wish to implement it in PHP and fetch data from Mysql. I don't think so this is the issue but wish to make sure.

Comment: None of those. I used [Sense Dashboard from Marvel](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/marvel-1.3/sense.html).

Comment: Can you show me a document from your index? But exactly how ES is giving it back to you. For example `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "size": 1
}'`. Provide the output of that command, please.

Comment: It returns me {"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":4,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"blog","_type":"post","_id":"4","_score":1.0,"_source":{"user": "aniket","body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word" , "title": "Two times word"}}]}}c

Comment: I think the problem is with the way you run the query. Somehow, depending on your shell or programming language, you might need to escape the single quotes from `_index['body']`. Just an attempt: can you try `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "termInfo=_index['"'"'body'"'"'][term].tf();return termInfo;",
      "params": {
        "term": "word"
      },
      "lang": "groovy",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}'`?

Comment: Waoo thanks Andrei..now its working..we spent lots of time just because of single quotes.

Comment: Finally, we found the reason :-).