# Find number of times we have a word in a row in elastic search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am working on elasticsearch and facing an issue that how many time a word comes in a row at the time search records.
Like I have following rows:

```
{
{ "user":"Aniket", "postDate":"2016-04-26","body":"Search as we discuss yesterday one time word", "title":"One time word"}
}, 
{
"user": "aniket", "postDate": "2016-04-26", "body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word word word" , "title": "Four times word"}
}, 
{"user": "aniket", "postDate": "2016-04-26", "body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word word" , "title": "Three times word"}
}, 
{"user": "aniket", 
"postDate": "2016-04-26", 
"body": "Distribution is hard. Distribution should be easy.word word" ,
"title": "Two times word"
}
```

I have above four rows under user aniket and we have "word" in each row but sometimes it goes two,three,four or one time. I need the result like if I search for "word" and we found word four times in the result than it will come at the top like: 1. word word word word 2. word word word 3. word word 4. word I tried with score too but score is not going to provide me any information related to that.

I am trying the following query

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/blog/post/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
"query": {
"match": {
"body": "word"
}
},
"sort": {
"_script": {
"type": "number",
"script": "termInfo=_index['body'][term].tf();return termInfo;",
"params": {
"term": "word"
},
"lang": "groovy",
"order": "desc"
}
}
}'
```

and getting this error:

```
{
"index" : "blog",
"shard" : 4,
"status" : 500,
"reason" : "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[blog][4]: query[filtered(body:word)->cache(type:post)],from[0],size[10],sort[script\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.DoubleScriptDataComparator$InnerSource@51c07776>!]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: body for class: Script5]]; "
} ]
```

If I remove the sort part of my query than its give me the result even if I use simple sort then body and order by asc than also it works properly but not is our word count case. Any solution for that and what I am missing?

Comment: Follow these instructions: http://blog.rnf.me/2013/exact-substring-search-in-elasticsearch.html

Comment: Just like I asked in your other post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889503/find-number-of-times-we-have-a-character-in-a-row-in-elastic-search - please provide the output of `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/blog/post/_search" -d' { "query": {"match_all": {}}, "size": 1 }'`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my instruction on [sort result by term frequency count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939959/sort-result-by-term-frequency-count) and check the content of "*_explanation*":

```
 "_explanation": {
          "value": 0.16608895,
          "description": "weight(_all:godfather in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.16608895,
              "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1.7320508,
                  "description": "tf(freq=3.0), with freq of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 3,
                      "description": "termFreq=3.0",
                      "details": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.30685282,
                  "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)",
                  "details": []
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.3125,
                  "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)",
                  "details": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

which has count of the word:

```
"value": 3,
"description": "termFreq=3.0",
"details": []
```